# salesforce : find fiscal quarter current month in apex class

Tags: custom-fiscal-year

[image]

Please help me to find out the first date of "this fiscal quarter" current month.
I'm able to find the start date of fiscal quarter from below query but my requirement is to find the current month start date.

Select StartDate From Period Where type = 'Quarter' and StartDate = THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER

ex : if current date is - 30th Dec 16 then the week start date is 25th dec 16
and based on this first date of current fiscal month would be 28th Nov.

please provide me apex code / formula to find out the date -> 28-11-2016

Comment: Does the fiscal month include both Nov 28 and Dec 30? That'd be a long month.

Comment: What if you compared the start date with the currentDate.tostartofmonth() and if > then return start date if not return the currentDate.toStartOfMonth(). Other than that a bit confused why the FQ Start date or the start of the current month would not be what you wanted

Comment: can you please give me an example, w.r.t to above quarter chart . thanks

Comment: can any one please help me with this solution ?